# I created a class in a console application, now I want to create a windows form applocation that uses that class

Tags: c#

I have created a button called "authenticate", and two text boxes so the program can get some user input. When the authenticate button is clicked, I want the program to either return "Authenticated" or "NOT Authenticated" depending on whether or not username and password matches. Anybody know a way of doing this? New to C#, thank you. I have added the class below for reference.

```
class Authenticator
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Authenticator au = new Authenticator();
        au.InitialValues();
       if (au.Authenticate())
          Console.WriteLine("Authenticated");
       else
          Console.WriteLine("NOT Authenticated");
          Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end");
          Console.ReadLine();
     }

     private Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

     public void InitialValues()
     {
          dictionary.Add("username1", "password1");
          dictionary.Add("username2", "password2");
          dictionary.Add("username3", "password3");
          dictionary.Add("username4", "password4");
          dictionary.Add("username5", "password5");
     }

     public bool Authenticate()
     {
          bool authenticated = false;

          Console.WriteLine("Please enter a username");
          string inputUsername = Console.ReadLine();

          Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password");
          string inputPassword = Console.ReadLine();

          if (dictionary.ContainsKey(inputUsername) && dictionary[inputUsername] == inputPassword)
          {
              authenticated = true;
          }
          else
          {
              authenticated = false;
          }

          return authenticated;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant. or at least its not a good way. you have to move this code in to your form class and use it there.

Comment: Your `Authenticate` part works fine. All you need to do is add two text boxes (username, password) and a button to a windows form and send the textbox values to `Authenticate` method on click of the button. Did you try to create the form and having problem there?

Comment: @ArghyaC, I can do that yeah, but I'm not sure on how to have the dictionary in there too as that is where the values are stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just reference the Console project in the windows forms project (exe-File). This is not a good practice. It would be better to put your reused code in a Library project which will be referenced by both the Console and the Forms project.

Oh and note that you code will not work in a Forms project without console.

Add the Class Library project howto:

In your solution create a new project (right click Add->New Project) and choose Class Library. After this you right click on your console or forms project and choose Add->Reference. In the dialog go to Project Reference and check the newly created Class Library. Now copy your class except the Main function into the Class Library project and compile.  Just pay attention that you rename your projects.

To make the authentication work you should use parameters instead of Console.ReadLine.

In class library

```
public class Authentication
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Authentication()
    {
        dictionary.Add("username1", "password1");
        dictionary.Add("username2", "password2");
        dictionary.Add("username3", "password3");
        dictionary.Add("username4", "password4");
        dictionary.Add("username5", "password5");
    }

    public bool Authenticate(string user, string password)
    {
        // note i just replaced the variable with return
        return dictionary.ContainsKey(user) && dictionary[user] == password;
    }
}
```

In your console application

```
Main(...)
{
    // ...
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a username");
    var user = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password");
    var password = Console.ReadLine();

    var auth = new Authentication();

    if(auth.Authenticate(user, password))
    { // do what you need to do ;) }
}
```

Note that your authentication mechanism is not secure. So don't use it where it is really important to have security.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, any tips on how to go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what do you mean by main function?

Comment: The static void Main(string[] args)

Comment: Hi, I seem to get this error: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Authentication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you need to include the namespace where you defined Authentication with a using in the top of the file. For example using MyNewLibrary; Depends on the namespace which where your Authentication class is defined. http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/07/understanding-c-namespaces-and.html

Comment: so if my class library class is called _djv_class, and my console class is called _djv, I should change my console class to _djv_class too? if that makes any sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93183/discussion-between-saco-and-cdv29).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make a solution with three diferent projects:

1. Logic (Class Library Project): it will have a class with your validation logic methods;
2. Console Application: it will have a reference to Logic, and make use of its methods to validate and display results in a console;
3. WinForms Application: the same as Console, but showing the results in a form

I suggest:

## Logic

```
public class MyLogic()
{
    public void InitializeData()
    {
       ...
    }


    public boolean Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
       if(....)
       {
          return true;
       }
       else
       {
          return false;
       }
    }
}
```

## Console Application

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine('Enter your username: ');
  string username = Console.ReadLine();

  Console.WriteLine('Enter your password: ');
  string password= Console.ReadLine();

  var logic = new MyLogic();
  logic.InitializeData();
  if(logic.Authenticate(username, password))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Success")
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Fail");
  }
}
```

## WinForms Application

Here, you can make the same as in Console, but showing the results in a Popup, in a label or wherever you want. I think you can catch the idea.

Comment: InitializeData should be called from the constructor if not lazy loading or something is required.

Comment: Yes, it should be better, but I wanted to keep it simple for the sake of simplicity

Comment: I'm confused as to what the InitializeData() is meant to be. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I meant InitializeValues(). It just initializes the users and passwords in the same way you did it, but now they are available for Console and WinForms.